# Htaccess rewrite url to lookup files in subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a web structure like this :

```
root/
|-> lib/
|-> web/
   |-> css/
   |-> index.html
|-> .htaccess
```

I would like, when a user requests a file, apache actually lookup in the web subfolder but without redirecting.

exemple : http://www.website.com/root/index.html the requested file is root/web/index.html but the url remains unchanged

Is there any way to accomplish that with the mod-rewrite (or anything else) and the .htaccess under root BUT without indicating the root (or domain) so that any "root" will work without modifying the .htaccess (for exemple if I rename root to "mynewroot") ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in `root/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(?!web/).*$ web/$0 [L,NC]
```

`(?!web/)` is negative lookahead to stop rewriting if request already starts with `/web/`

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. Move your .htaccess to the parent folder where your "root" folder is located and use a wildcard rewrite rule.

In your case:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1/web/ [L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the root's parent folder ; it has to be this very .htaccess (root/.htaccess)

Comment: Well reading your question, I assumed that the folder "root" wasn't actually your root folder since you point it to http://www.website.com/root/index.html , if that's the case and you only have access to the folder root on this domain, then all URL's you rewrite must start with /root/

Comment: root could actually be anything, i'm looking for a script that will redirect all request to a given subfolder of the current one, no matter what root it is.